# Post-build ditrective syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

I received this dreaded error, related to ClosedXML, when I deployed my project to the server.

The project runs locally, though.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So I placed the "missing" DLL file in /binDLL

**I then added the following cmd line directive:**

```
Copy "$(SolutionDir)binDLL\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll" "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)"
```

**When I build, I get a build error**

```
Error   17  The command "Copy "C:\Projects\MyProject\binDLL\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll" "C:\Projects\MyProject\bin\"" exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a reason to do it like this. Simply open References in Solution Explorer, right click on the reference in question, choose `Properties` and set `Copy Local` to True. That should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, that worked when I tried it today. I thought I did that before I posted and it was not working right. Thanks for reaffirming